# How to display differences in prices using switch statements in C++

Tags: c++, switch-statement

For a class project I have to develop a program that calculates the cost of a mobile device service. There are 3 packages the user can choose from. The cost of the service is determined by the base price and number of message units to be used. After the user chooses a package I have to let them know the price of the package as well as letting them know if either of the other packages would be cheaper and show what the difference in price would be by using switch statements. I've wrote some switch statements comparing the packages, but how do I show and calculate how much they would save if there is a cheaper package than the one chosen? I am also a beginner so take it easy.

```
int main() {
    bool finished = false;

    do {
        // to keep it simple
        double choice_a = 9.95;
        double choice_b = 19.95;
        double choice_c = 39.95;
        char choice;
        int message_units;
        double price;
        bool selected = false;
        // this loop shows the options initially
        do {
            cout << "Which package do you choose (enter A, B or C)" << endl;
            // you will need to check this
            cin >> choice;
            // keeping it simple
            if (choice == 'A') { price = choice_a; selected = true; }
            else if (choice == 'B') { price = choice_b; selected = true; }
            else if (choice == 'C') { price = choice_c; selected = true; }
            cout << endl;
        }
        // loops until something was selected
        while (selected == false);

        // user enters how many units is wanted
        cout << "How many message units (enter 1 - 672)" << endl;
        // again check this (if homework requires checking input)
        cin >> message_units;

        // Calculating message units
        if(message_units > 5){
            price += 100 * (message_units - 5);
        }
        if(message_units > 15){
            price += 50 * (message_units - 15);
        }

        // Total Price Output
        cout << "Your total cost is " << price/100 << endl

        // Is user done?
        char done;
        cout << "Do you want to enter another? press enter to continue.
        cin >> done;

        // check
        if (done != ' ') {
            finished = true;
        }
    }
    while (finished = false);
}

switch (choice)
{
    case 'A':
    if(choice_b < choice_a);
    cout << "You can save by switching to package B" << endl;
    else if(choice_c < choice_a);
    cout << "You can save by switching to package C" << endl;
    break;
    case 'B':
    if(choice_a < choice_b);
    cout << "You can save by switching to package A" << endl;
    else if(choice_c < choice_b);
    cout << "You can save by switching to package C" << endl;
    break;
    case 'C':
    if(choice_a < choice_c);
    cout << "You can save by switching to package A" << endl;
    else if(choice_b < choice_c);
    cout << "You can save by switching to package B" << endl;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are comparing the two with the same quantity,

Savings = [(Selection Price) - (Cheaper Option Price)]× Quantity

If you do this calculation and say assign it to a type double called Savings, you can print this out.

cout << "Savings are "<< Savings;

Doing this on each if  statement is simple, but of course there are better ways to do this. Such as calling a function that does this simple calculation for two options.

EDIT 1: Apologize for the poor formatting, this is on my phone.

EDIT 2: Also noticed you have incorrect syntax with your control loops. Here is a good resource [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/)

EDIT 3: There are actually a number of other issues including your switch statement being outside of main.

This line doesn't make sense, in practical terms.

// Calculating message units if(message_units > 5){ price += 100 * (message_units - 5); } if(message_units > 15){ price += 50 * (message_units - 15); }

Good practice would suggest not overwriting a variable with a value with a different meaning. It is confusing. Initially it seems price is the per quantity price. Then it looks like you try to assign the overall cost to it.

(I'm assuming; it doesn't actually do this. Instead it adds a price of 100 per unit except for the first 5 to a single unit price you declare at the top. Similarly for the greater than 15 block.)

EDIT 4: Per request in comments:

If I am correct in what I think you are trying to do, replace this block:

```
// Calculating message units
    if(message_units > 5){
        price += 100 * (message_units - 5);
    }
    if(message_units > 15){
        price += 50 * (message_units - 15);
    }
```

with:

```
double Total_Cost;
if(message_units => 5 && message_units<15){
    Total_Cost = price * (message_units - 5);
}
else if(message_units => 15){
    Total_Cost = price * (message_units - 15);
}
else{
    Total_Cost = price * message_units;
}
```

That is 'you get the first 5 free (or 15) if you buy in bulk'.  Otherwise it is just the price times the number of units.  This again seems kind of strange, but this is what this does.

Comment: What should my formula look like because when I output the price the decimal point is out of place?

Comment: It didn't work. For my project I have to add 1.00 per message unit to package A if more than five message units entered. Also I have to add .50 per message unit to package B if more than 15 message units are entered.

Comment: I see. My  misunderstanding. Is you price declaration in cents at the top then? Hope this helped at least.

Comment: Yes its at the top. Ive been trying for days to get the equation right. Now that you know what I have to calculate can you give me an idea what my equation should like. Every time I run it the decimal point is in the wrong spot. For example if a user picked package A and picked six units the correct price output should read 10.95

Comment: It'd be easier to identify if you tell me you are getting now.

Comment: When I run the program and choose package A and input 6 message units the price output is 1.0995. The correct price should be 10.95. When i choose Package B and choose 16 units which would add .50 to the total it outputs 11.6995? When it should be 20.45 because 19.95 + .50 = 20.45

Comment: Are you sure you aren't reading 1,099.5 and 11,699.5?   Two things:
1) It seems like you haven't changed the if loop to only do the first condition if
  message_units => 5 && message_units<15

and the second condition should be an else if.  Otherwise both actions are executed if message_units>15.  

2) If you only only want to add $1 to $9.95, 100 should be 1.00.  Similarly if you want to add 1cent to 9.95cents, 100 should be 1.00.  Same logic to the 50.  These are very simple mistakes.  Be sure to thoroughly read your code.

Comment: @AlanBarnett, if one of the answers provided here answered your question, please mark it as answered to close the question.  Thanks. Hope you resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 int main() {
    bool finished = false;
    char choice;
    double choice_a = 9.95;
    double choice_b = 19.95;
    double choice_c = 39.95;
    int message_units;
    double price;
    bool selected = false;

    do {
        // to keep it simple
        // this loop shows the options initially
        do {
            cout << "Which package do you choose (enter A, B or C)" << endl;
            // you will need to check this
            cin >> choice;
            // keeping it simple
            if (choice == 'A') { price = choice_a; selected = true; }
            else if (choice == 'B') { price = choice_b; selected = true; }
            else if (choice == 'C') { price = choice_c; selected = true; }
            cout << endl;
        }
        // loops until something was selected
        while (selected == false);

        // user enters how many units is wanted
        cout << "How many message units (enter 1 - 672)" << endl;
        // again check this (if homework requires checking input)
        cin >> message_units;

        // Calculating message units
        if(message_units > 5){
            price += 100 * (message_units - 5);
        }
        if(message_units > 15){
            price += 50 * (message_units - 15);
        }

        // Total Price Output
        cout << "Your total cost is " << price/100 << endl;

         switch (choice)
         {
         case 'A':
         if(choice_b < choice_a)
         cout << "you can save by switching to package B it saves: " << choice_a - choice_b << " if you choose B" << endl;
         else if(choice_c < choice_a)
         cout << "You can save by switching to package C is saves: " << choice_a - choice_c << endl;
         break;
         case 'B':
         if(choice_a < choice_b)
         cout << "you can save by switching to package A it saves: " << choice_b - choice_a << " if you choose a" << endl;
         else if(choice_c < choice_b)
         cout << "you can save by switching to package C it saves: " << choice_b - choice_c << " if you choose c" << endl;
         break;
         case 'C':
         if(choice_a < choice_c)
         cout << "you can save by switching to package A it saves: " << choice_c - choice_a << " if you choose a" << endl;
         else if(choice_b < choice_c)
         cout << "you can save by switching to package A it saves: " << choice_c - choice_b << " if you choose b" << endl;
         break;
         }

        // Is user done?
        char done;
        cout << "Do you want to enter another? press enter to continue.";
        cin >> done;

        // check
        if (done != ' ') {
            finished = true;
        }

    }
    while (finished == false);


}
```

sorry for not explaining but i try explaining it the best i can 
    based on your code. i fix some wrong syntaxe and tries to match the problem 
    you've post so i defined all the variables you've created outside the first
    outer bool so that the switch statement will work and i edit some code in the switch statement to calculate the amount of savings and displays them based on the conditions sorry for bad english.

Comment: Given the OP stated they are a beginner, it might be useful to the learning process if you explained your answer in detail, rather than just posting the code that solves the problem.

Comment: @Thanks man do u guys get paid to help or u just love programming that much?

Comment: both because i like programming and helping people :)

Comment: Ok my calculating message units section of my code still does not give me the right output. The decimal is not in the right place when I run it. For my project I have to add 1.00 per message unit to package A if more than five message units entered. Also I have to add .50 per message unit to package B if more than 15 message units are entered.